# iAd doesn't appear after release

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, app-store-connect, iad

I made a game with SpriteKit - Swift, and it was released on 23, March 2015. I added an interstitial ad when the user lose, and it worked when I tested it on my own iPhone (with the test interstitial ad), but after the release on the App Store, I downloaded it and I tried many times, but the ad never appeared, and it was the same thing for my friends !

I saw that the application need to be downloaded a number of times to the pubs are displayed. My game was downloaded only 60 times, is this the case ?

On iAd Network, I have this message :

> iAd Network is temporarily unavailable. Sorry: We were unable to locate information relating to your account. Please try again later. If the problem persist please contact us.

So I contacted Apple two weeks ago, but got no answer.

Anyone is in the same case ? Please help me, I can't earn money with my game !

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6032666